# How to change string value with function in C?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

```
void change(char *string){
    string = "Hello";
    printf("%s", string);
}

int main (void){
    char* s = "Hey";
    change(s);
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't the code above print "Hello", as the parameter passed to the function is a pointer?

Comment: In `change` yes, in `main` no, because you passed a *copy* of `s` to the function. So the original value is unchanged. It wouldn't have done you any good to use `strcpy()` either, because `s` is a string literal, (and is too short anyway). You would have to pass a double star pointer, and use indirection: `*string = "Hello";`

Comment: Which arguments should I pass to a void change() Function in order for it to change the value of the variable globally?

Comment: It isn't a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

pass a char** if you want a reference to a pointer. Then you can change where the pointer in main points to.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do what you want.  The most common are shown below.  It might be worth investigating this to understand what's happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void
change(char const **string)
{
    *string = "Hello";
}

void
change2(char * string, size_t n)
{
    strncpy(string, "hello", n - 1);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char const *cs = "Hey";
    char * s;
    char buf1[32] = "ABC";
    char buf2[] = "XYZ";

    change(&cs);   
    change2(s = buf1, sizeof buf1);
    change2(s = buf2, sizeof buf2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, your code *shouldn't* print "Hello" just because you have a *pointer* (to the first byte of a *string*).

#### What does your code actually do?

Consider this example memory layout:

```
         +0    +1    +2    +3
0x1000 : 'H' | 'e' | 'y' | x00  
0x1004 : 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l'
0x1008 : 'o' | x00 | xFE | xFE
```

The bytes for the string literal `0x1000` start at address `0x1000` and the bytes for the string literal `"Hello"` start at address `0x1004`.  They may even be stored in read-only memory.

```
char* s = "Hey";
```

`s` is a variable that stores an *address*.  It is the address `0x1000` in memory (a pointer to `"Hey"`).

```
change(s);

void change(char *string){
```

When you call `change` you pass the value of `s` to the function and it gets assigned to the parameter `string`.  It's almost like saying `string = s`. So, inside the function, `string` now contains the address `0x1000` as well.

The parameter `string` works like a local variable in that you are allowed to change the value it has. Remember that its value is just an *address*.  Changing this value does not alter the bytes of the string.

```
string = "Hello";
```

You assign `string` the value `0x1004` (a pointer to `"Hello"`). At this point the variable `s` still contains the value `0x1000` and it remains to be the value `0x1000` after the call to `change`.  But the variable `string` now has the value `0x1004` which points to the first byte of the string `"Hello"`.

When you pass `s` to `printf` you are asking it to print the string at the address stored in `s`, which is still the address `0x1000`, and therefore you print `Hey`.

---

#### What if you really want to change `s`?

One could potentially pass the address of the variable `s` itself if you wanted to be able to modify it.  Since `s` is of type `char*`, a pointer to `s` would be of type `char**`.

```
char* s = "Hey";
char** ptr = &s;
(*ptr) = "Hello";
printf("%s", s);
```

*(I wrote the above without the function call for brevity, but you could just as easily make your function `void change(char** ptr)` and call `change(&s)`.)*

To visualize this we need to include where the storage for `s` is in memory and agree on how many bytes it takes to store a memory address.  In my imaginary example platform a memory address is 2 bytes.  (sizeof void* is 2, and addresses are stored with little endianness (least significant byte first))

> Note it depends on your platform what the size of a pointer (memory address) is.  It could be 4 bytes (on 32-bit architecture) or even 8 bytes (on 64-bit architecture).

```
         +0    +1    +2    +3
0x1000 : 'H' | 'e' | 'y' | x00  
0x1004 : 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l'
0x1008 : 'o' | x00 | xFE | xFE
0x100C : x00 | x10 | xFE | xFE
```

The variable `s` is stored in memory at location `0x100C` (it's 2 bytes long in this pretend case so it also occupies the byte at `0x100D`).  Its initial value is `0x1000` (points to `"Hey"`)

```
ptr = &s;
```

Now `ptr` holds the value `0x100C` (the address of `s`)

```
(*ptr) = "Hello";
```

Now `s` holds the value `0x1004`.  And the bytes at address `0x100C` and `0x100D` are updated to store the address `0x1004`.

```
0x100C : x04 | x10 | xFE | xFE
```

`s` now contains the value `0x1004` and points to the first byte of the string `"Hello"`.  Note, that at no point did we modify the bytes of the string literals themselves - they're constant.  We're just manipulating addresses.

Complete example:

```
void change(char **pString){
    (*pString) = "Hello";
    printf("%s", (*pString));
}

int main (void){
    char* s = "Hey";
    change(&s);
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```